# DB2 right padding with field length

Tags: db2

We have fields with varying lengths and want to right-pad them with spaces to the field length defined in the schema.

The following statement is working:

```
SELECT RPAD(field, LENGTH(field), ' ') AS field FROM schema.table;
```

This produces an SQL error 206 with SQLState 42703: is not valid in the context where it is used.

```
// Our application resolves the prepared statement's ? - this is working fine
INSERT INTO schema.table (field) VALUES (RPAD(?, LENGTH(field), ' '));
```

The same happens with:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (field) VALUES (RPAD(?, LENGTH(schema.table.field), ' '));
```

Is there any possibility to avoid hardcoding the field length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that scalar functions operate on rows; `LENGTH(field)` only works within a statement that returns rows, such as a select statement.  To understand why, imagine putting some other function in place of `LENGTH()`. `LCASE(field)`, for example, takes the lowercase of the string in a particular row.  It wouldn't make sense applied generically to a column.  Even `LENGTH()` can vary row-by-row in some cases: if the column is of type `VARCHAR`, `LENGTH()` returns the length of the actual string.

The solution is to select any row, perform the `LENGTH()` operation on the field, and store the result in a variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE field_length INTEGER;
SET field_length = (
    SELECT LENGTH(field) FROM schema.table 
        WHERE field IS NOT NULL
        FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
);
```

You only need to do this once in your code.  Then, whenever you need to use the length:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (field) VALUES (RPAD(?, field_length, ' '));
```

Note that this solution depends on `field` being defined as a `CHAR(x)` rather than a `VARCHAR(x)`.  If you had to do this with a `VARCHAR`, you could find out the length of the field from the `syscat.columns` system table.

EDIT: added handling of null values since `LENGTH()` could return null if the value in `field` is null.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! And yes, we're using ``VARCHAR`` (for no good reason)...

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fixed length column, why are you using `VARCHAR`?  Use `CHAR` - DB2 will automatically pad the values for you.

Comment: Multiple Cobol and Host (via some replication) applications use that database. It should indeed be ``CHAR``, but we must not change anything in the database for fear of new issues...